# Atmospheric Re-entry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, particles

I'm using Blender 2.75 Cycles, I'm looking at trying to create
an atmospheric re-entry scene.

So I'm looking for a node setup to create something like this image by using particles or some alternative method. I have attempted to use the smoke simulator but the issue is my CPU is quite slow and GPU smoke rendering doesn't seem to be supported yet.
[image]

Comment: Smoke rendering is supported in GPU starting with version 2.77

Answer (score 1):

I would model the reddish smoke as a solid object, parented with the ship, move it in it's own layer, set to a new render layer.

In the compositor you can blur it, make it transparent, add some noise texture to bring some life, mask some parts to animate it .....

Fast rendering and effective results

Comment: Sounds like it could work, what would you recommend for the initial material setup? I was thinking maybe a red glass material. Also you talk about masking, I don't know what that is, unfortunately.

Comment: If it's gonna be animated, I would do a simple red diffuse material, for fast rendering. In the compositor you can create a Matte - ellipse mask, blur it, mutiply with your red smoke and animate dimensions and location of the mask, to make the smoke appear, disappear, big, little ....